# How to embed secrets into a file that the Dockerfile accesses via GitHub Actions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, github-actions, github-secret, python-pdm

## Need:

- I am trying to create a Docker image that is needed for Google's Dataflow resource.
- The Docker file needs to, among other things, perform a `pdm install` (pdm is a Python build tool similar to poetry)
- Some of what it is installing are private packages on our GCP Artifact Registry.
- I am using the [Buildx docker build and push](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) GitHub action.
- So I need to inject secrets into the build and push action, that can then be read by the Dockerfile.

## Search:

I have looked at the following possible solutions, and I cannot get anything to work for me:

- [SO: Docker passing secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405212/safe-way-to-use-build-time-argument-in-docker/51921954#51921954)
- [SO: Accessing Docker secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697813/accessing-secrets-private-files-needed-for-building-in-dockerfile)
- [Docker Docs: using GHA secrets with Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/secrets/)
- [Docker Docs: examples of secrets with Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#secret)

## Representative Example of my case:

There are many tasks that I am trying to do, so I will just create a simplified set of files that are representative of my issue.

`docker-build.yaml` GitHub Action:

```yaml
env:
  PYTHON_REPO_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PYTHON_REPO_PASSWORD }}
.
.
.
      - name: mytest
        run: |
           echo ${{ env.PYTHON_REPO_PASSWORD }}
           cat ${{ inputs.working-directory }}/pyproject.toml
           cat ${{ inputs.working-directory }}/pyproject.toml > ${{ inputs.working-directory }}/pyproject.toml
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          push: true
          tags: my/app:latest
          file: ${{ inputs.working-directory }}/${{ inputs.dockerfile }}
          context: ${{ inputs.working-directory }}
        secrets: inherit # I have also tried by explicitly setting the secrets
```

The `mytest` step is in there to verify if the secrets are even in there.  Yes, the secret is "shown" (with only `***`, of course), including in the `pyproject.toml` file, described below, so that the URL for the artifact registry with the password embedded is properly rendered.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM apache/beam_python3.11_sdk:2.51.0 AS foundation
WORKDIR /project
COPY pyproject.toml pdm.lock README.md ./
COPY src/ ./src
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=PYTHON_REPO_PASSWORD \
    pip install -U pip setuptools wheel pdm && \
    pdm install --prod --no-lock --no-editable
```

The final step here, the `pdm install` with only flags after it, is the step that builds what is in the `pyproject.toml` file below.

`pyproject.toml` Python build file:

```ini
[project]
name = "aggregatedata"
dependencies = [
    "apache-beam[gcp]>=2.51",
    "phxdataflow", # This is the private package that I need to access
    "google-cloud-logging>=3.8.0",
]

[[tool.pdm.source]]
name = "insights_python_packages"
url = "https://_json_key_base64:$PYTHON_REPO_PASSWORD@us-west1-python.pkg.dev/prj-phalanx-mgmt-infra/insights-python-packages/simple/"
```

Again, in the `mytest` step, the `pyproject.toml` file above is being rendered properly so that the URL has the secret embedded into it.

But when the Dockerfile `RUN pdm install` command runs, the secret is not being injected.  I cannot get a detailed log of the Dockerfile, except that `pdm` is *unable* to find `phxdataflow` when I use the secret, and it works fine if I just paste the actual password. So I know the problem is somehow with the injection into `pyproject.toml` during the `Dockerfile` build steps.

## Solution

I don't *need* to solve it in the way described above... I just need for a secret that exists in the GHA build agent environment to make it into the `pyproject.toml` file *when* the `Dockerfile` is reading it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to replace the string value by the secret during the workflow process? Could be through a `sed` command or even an action on the Marketplace (i've created one to do this for my Kubernetes manifests [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/replace-values-action) if you want to have a look)

Comment: Inheriting secrets is only for _jobs_, not steps: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsecretsinherit. To pass secrets _into_ the container see e.g. https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/secrets/.

Comment: @GuiFalourd , yes, I also tried using `sed` to replace the secrets in the `pyproject.toml`.  However, I need to do that WITHIN the docker image build.  So I still have the same problem, the secrets are not available while building, for a reason that I don't understand.  So, the secrets were lost.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's unfortunately the same link that I provided.  Yes, it can get secrets into the job & step, but then for some reason they do not get into the Dockerfile and Docker image build.

Comment: But it's not what you've actually _shown_, please give a [mre] of something that _could_ work.