# How to manage environment variables that point to credential files in docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables, credentials, docker-container

In my `~/.bashrc`, I have set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=~/.gc/credential_file_name.json`.

My source code is located in (and I'm working from here) `~/repos/github_repo/` where I have a Dockerfile with its working directory set to `/usr/src/app`.

If I copy `~/.gc/credential_file_name.json` to `~/repos/github_repo/credential_file_name.json` and run the docker container with

```
docker run -t \
    -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/src/app/credential_file_name.json \
    ...
```

the credential file gets picked up and subsequent code runs ok.

But, ideally, I don't want to copy the credential to my github repository, as that risks possibly pushing it on github (even when I add it to .gitignore, it's still not safe).

Additionally, instead of having to explicitly give then full path `-e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/src/app/credential_file_name.json`, I would like to do something like `-e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}` where `${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}` gets picked up from my `~/.bashrc`.

But obviously, `${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}` will point to a path on my computer, which different directory structure than the docker container.

What is the best way to resolve this? I'm new to this and I came across `direnv` and `.envrc`, but don't quite understand.

I'm using Makefile to run the docker commands. I will try to avoid docker-compose, but if it solves this problem, please let me know.

Thanks for help!

Comment: `${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS} will point to a path on my computer` Great, so now you can `-v ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}:${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}:ro`

Comment: [Docker and securing passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651647/docker-and-securing-passwords) may have some relevant advice.  The host and container paths don't have to match, and one legitimate option is to mount the file to a fixed container path.

Comment: @KamilCuk great, thank you this solved it. If you post an answer, I will accept it as the best.